# Best way of Packaging and Deploying a Wpf application. I could Not able to build using visual studio installer project from command line

Tags: wpf

I want to create .EXE or .MSI for WPF application. I tried with Visual Studio Installer(Setup) project. But the problem is I could not able to build the setup project from command line, because I have to configure automatic builds for wpf application in Jenkins. I am getting HRESULT '8000000A' error(building with Vs2017). So I wanted to go with different procedure which should support following features.

1. Should create .exe or .msi. if possible both.
2. Silent installation of msi or exe
3. Should build from command line.
4. Easy to configure with Jenkins build(build script for msi or exe)
5. Upgrading Support

We have licence for WISE Installation Wizard. Is it good to go with WISE. Because already I have spent time on visual studio installer, I don't want any surprises in future.

Comment: I am Developing application in VS2017 with framework version 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Karun,

You definitely need to get clear with **MSI** and **WIX**. That's probably the single way to create custom installers. I'm afraid it's impossible to totally explain it here - I've spent so many days and weeks to figure out some details to create custom installer. And even now I'm not sure I'm so confident in it...

So - here is the list of steps I'd do:

1. Read a bit what the **MSI** is and what the **WIX** is.
2. Check [WIX Toolset web-site](https://wixtoolset.org/) it's pretty fresh (as for MS based technology :) ) and not so boring.
3. Download some of the basic **WIX** example. Try to understand what are *MSI.Installer*, *Wix.Installer*, *Bootstrapper* and how do they're connected with each other.
4. Working with an example you'll get new but more detailed questions that can be Goggled or it will be more constructive to ask somebody here.

Anyway, hope I could make it clear for a bit.

Good luck.